# use dplyr to select columns

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

I'm trying to use the `select` function of `dplyr` to extract columns of another dataframe.

Here the data frame:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(Al = c(30245, 38060, 36280, 24355, 27776, 35190, 
38733.8, 36400, 29624, 33699.75), As = c(9, 8.75, 13.5, 7.75, 
7.6, 8.33, 8, 8.75, 7.4, 8.25), Cd = c(0.15, 0.13, 0.15, 0.1, 
0.16, 0.13, 0.24, 0.15, 0.22, 0.13), Cr = c(108.5, 111.75, 104.5, 
81.25, 93.2, 109.75, 105, 104, 87.8, 99.75), Hg = c(0.25, 0.35, 
0.48, 1.03, 1.12, 0.2, 1.14, 0.4, 2, 0.48)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Al", "As", "Cd", "Cr", 
"Hg"))
```

and here the character vector I want to use as filter:

```
dput(vec_fil)
c("Elemento", "As", "Cd_totale", "Cr_totale", "Cu_totale", "Hg", 
"Ni_totale", "Pb_totale", "Zn_totale", "Composti_organostannici", 
"PCB_totali", "Sommatoria_DDD", "Sommatoria_DDE", "Sommatoria_DDT", 
"Clordano", "Dieldrin", "Endrin", "Esaclorocicloesano", "Eptacloro_epossido", 
"Sommatoria_IPA", "Acenaftene", "Antracene", "Benzo.a.antracene", 
"Benzo.a.pirene", "Crisene", "Dibenzo.ac._.ah.antracene", "Fenantrene", 
"Fluorantene", "Fluorene", "Naftalene", "Pirene")
```

As you can see `vec_fil` has many characters that don't match the columns of df1, so I get this error:

```
require("dplyr")
df2 <- select(df1, one_of(vec_fil))
Error: Each argument must yield either positive or negative integers
```

Any hint I can use in order to get only the matched character of the filter vector in the new data frame?

Comment: Hi, it is not clear what you want to do or the result you are expecting, and where `one_of` does come from ? Maybe what you are trying to do is `df1[, names(df1) %in% vec_fil]`.

Comment: Hi, yes.. what you wrote is what I expected.. Is it possible to do the same with `dplyr`?

Comment: You could do something ridiculous as `select(df1, matches(paste(vec_fil, collapse = "|")))`, but I'm simply failing to understand why not to use base R in this situation.

Comment: yes, `select(df1, which(names(df1) %in% vec_fil))` should do the job

Comment: Great! Thanks to all of you! @Mamoun, if you post your comment as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can try this code in base R

```
df1[, names(df1) %in% vec_fil]
```

and if you want to use package `dplyr`

```
select(df1, which(names(df1) %in% vec_fil))
```

Answer (score 5):

I am late in the party. But, no one explain what was the reason for the error. So, I do.

You have wrongly used the `one_of()` in the `dplyr` package. According to the package documentation, it selects [all] the variables that are in the vector.

> one_of("x", "y", "z"): selects variables provided in a character vector.

It does not allow you to select a subset of variables from the `one_of()` vector though the name of the function implies that.

In your case, `vec_fil` vector has some feature names that do not exist in the data frame. Thus, it throws error. You should only use `one_of()` when you have a long list of feature names and you don't want to type them manually. So, you can read them directly from a list.

Hope it helps you in your future works.

Answer (score 3):

Just get rid of variable names not included in your data frame using `intersect`:

```
select(df1, one_of(intersect(vec_fil, names(df1))))
```